# How to skip DataRow insert if primary key will be violated in .NET DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following DataTable with a composite primary Key. The 4th time through the for loop the composite key would be violated. How can I say, if this row will cause the key to be violated, don't add it to the DataRowCollection? I just want rows in my DataTable that are unique based on the three keys. Thanks

```
DataTable DTRejects = new DataTable("RejectedInvoicesDT");
DTRejects.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
                      {
                          DTRejects.Columns.Add("OperatorName"),
                          DTRejects.Columns.Add("ProcessType"),
                          DTRejects.Columns.Add("RejectedReason")
                       };

  for (int i = 0; i < RowIndex; i++)
  {
  if (arrStatus[i].ToString() == "Rejected")
    {
        DataRow DRRejects = DTRejects.NewRow();
            DRRejects[0] = arrOperatorName[i].ToString();
            DRRejects[1] = arrProcessType[i].ToString();
            DRRejects[2] = arrRejectedReason[i].ToString();
    DTRejects.Rows.Add(DRRejects);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply an in-logic distinct prior. This is easy with LINQ and [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
 var statuses = Range(0, RowIndex)
     .Where(i => "Rejected".Equals(arrStatus[i]))
     .Select(i => new {
         OperatorName = Convert.ToString(arrOperatorName[i]),
         ProcessType = Convert.ToString(arrProcessType[i]),
         RejectedReason = Convert.ToString(arrRejectedReason[i]),
     })
     .Distinct();

 foreach (var status in statuses)
 {
    dtRejects.Rows.Add(new object [] {
      status.OperatorName, status.ProcessType, status.RejectedReason
    });
 }
```

Comment: That works real nicely. I'm going to look at what else I might be able to do using Linq. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the generic types of DataTable but if you create a Strong Typed dataset you can create strong typed DataTables as well, using the designer.

On a strong typed datatable you can define your primary key, using the designer.
You can enable or disable checking of constraints.
You get an easy to use find method to look in the table based on the values of the primary key values.

As such it would be easy to detect if a key already exists.
Of course using linq this is also easy as user2864740 in his answer is indicating but I have been using strong typed datasets already way before linq existed and they work too and it results is very readable code.